# steps by Euclidean algorithm back tracing

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

integers x and
y
such that gcd(2689
,
369) =
x
2689 +
y
369

I know the answer is  x = 94 and y = -685 But I really want know how can I trace it back by Euclidean algorithm if I know the gcd is 1.

My steps are

2689 , 369, 106, 51, 4, 3, 1, 0

But I dont know how to back trace this to get the x and y

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Exactly what* these steps are? They are:

> $$\begin{align} 2689 &=  7*369 &+&106 \\
> 369 &= 3*106 &+&51 \\
> 106 &= 2*51 &+&4 \\
> 51 &= 12*4 &+&3 \\
> 4 &=1*3&+&1
> \end{align} $$
>   So, reading these backwards, we have
>   $$\begin{align} 1&=4-1*3 \\
> 3 &=51-12*4 \\
> 4&=106-2*51\\
> 51&=369-3*106\\
> 106&=2689-7*369
> \end{align} $$
>   So that, summing them up:
>   $1=(106-2*51)-(51-12*4)$
>   then go on and substitute the next numbers using the above equations to get rid of $4$, then $51$, finally of $106$, leading to an expression of the form $x*2689-y*369$.

Comment: Oh and the answer is x = 94, y = 685